# Error with push.lua from CS50 game course

Tags: lua, cs50, love2d, pong

I have a problem with the folder "pong-1" that contains "main.lua" and "push.lua". When I select them into "LÖVE", it says:

```
>Error
push.lua:71: bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got number)
[C]: in function 'insert'
push.lua:71: in function 'setupCanvas'
main.lua:12: in function 'load'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

I tried with the outdated version of push.lua (which offers the source code of the course) as well as the newest version I could find, but neither of them worked. Both display the same error message. What could be the problem?

Comment: The code that you can download should run without any modifications. the error tells you that you provide a number value where a table is expected. did you modify the code? where did you download it? share the functions load and setupCanvas that are mentioned in the call stack

Comment: I just downloaded them from the github of push: https://github.com/Ulydev/push/blob/master/push.lua and put it into the "pong-1" folder without any modification. In the main.lua i did push = require 'push', so I suppose it should be okay. The function load in main is the following: function love.load()
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')
    push:setupCanvas(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,{
        fullscreen = false, resizable = false, vsync = true
    })
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function push:setupCanvas(canvases)
  table.insert(canvases, { name = "_render", private = true }) --final render

  self._canvas = true
  self.canvases = {}

  for i = 1, #canvases do
    push:addCanvas(canvases[i])
  end

  return self
end
```

This functions expects `canvases` to be a table value.

You provide a number value `VIRTUAL_WIDTH` in your function call

```
push:setupCanvas(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH,
  WINDOW_HEIGHT,{ fullscreen = false, resizable = false, vsync = true })
```

instead.

Looks like you're confusing `setupCanvas` with `setupScreen`